# Laravel rule validation unique for id

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a locations table which has a client_id foreign key which links to my Client table. I want to add form validation so that when a new location is created is it unique but only for a given client_id. So client one cant have two locations called America but Client one and two can both have America.

How do you do this with the laravel validation rules

Comment: What is your relationship please describe it. A location have many clients? or is it many to many

Comment: @HaiderAli the locations belongs to clients and client has many locations

Comment: if it is a 1 to many from location to clients then locations are already unique. What's the need of making location's unique then?

Comment: Alright. But in your question you said "Client one cant have two locations called America but Client one and two can both have America." which makes it a many to many relationship. Since to clients have the same location.

Comment: But any how you can validate the request for adding a location by simply adding validation rules as bro @Mehrdad Dastgir pointed out below

Comment: @HaiderAli The locations table has other fields like contact name, contact number, contact email. So the America for client one could have different contact information than the America for client two

Comment: yeah. That's why its a many to many relationship. How you describe it is conveys a client have many locations and a location may have many clients.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check the [laravel validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique) documentation. 
You can specify the table, column and id to ignore.

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,'.$user->id
```

You can also add additional where clauses:

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,NULL,id,account_id,1'
```

> In the rule above, only rows with an account_id of 1 would be included in the unique check.

Answer (score 1):

You can use laravel's built in unique validation as,

```
'client_id' => 'unique:Client table'
```

and at the time of edit you can pass exception for current row, like

```
'client_id' => 'unique:Client table,client_id,'.$id
```

I hope it helps,  Thank you...